# Objective C - Calling a static method on a Class type object?

Tags: objective-c, class, static-methods

I get the following error:
**Class is not an objective c class name**

```
- (void)CallStaticMethodForClass :(Class *)myClass
{
     [myClass doSomething];
}

+ (void)doSomething
{
     //
}
```

Comment: Objective-C does not have *static methods*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be declared as:

```
- (void)callMethodOnClass:(Class)myClass { ...
```

A couple things:

1. The pointer (`*`) is unnecessary when referring to a `Class`.  Command-double click "`Class`" to see why (it's part of the `typedef`)
2. We don't start our methods with a capital letter
3. There's no such thing as a "static" method in Objective-C.  We have "class methods".